# Appending input value to list using Javascript. To Do List

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to make a todo list.Not too sure why my code isn't working.Trying to get the value from the add item input to the To-Do ul.

HTML

```
<body>
<div class = 'container'>
<h3> Add Item </h3>
<input id='newTask' type='text'> <button id='addTaskButton'> Add </button>

<h3> To-Do </h3>
<ul id='toDo'>
<li> <input type='checkbox'<label> Learn Javascript </label> <button class='delete'> Delete </button> </li>
</ul>

<h3> Completed </h3> 
<ul id='completedTasks'>
<li> <input type='checkbox' checked> <label> Buy Peanut Butter </label> <button class='delete'> Delete </button> </li>
</ul>

</div>
<script src = "todolist.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
var taskInput = document.getElementById('newTask');
var addTaskButton = document.getElementById('addTaskButton');
var incompleteTasks = document.getElementById('toDo');
var completedTask = document.getElementById('completedTasks');

var addTask = function () {
    var text = taskInput.value;
    var li = '<li>' + text + '<li>';
    incompleteTasks.appendChild(li);

}

addTaskButton.onclick = addTask;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) accepts a DOMElement, not a string. You need to create an element first and then append it:

```
var addTask = function () {
    var text = taskInput.value;
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = text;
    incompleteTasks.appendChild(li);
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6wbsujL5/